# CRTP error with XCode 4.5.2 - Parse Issue, expected expression

Tags: c++, xcode, templates, clang, xcode4.5

I am using [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to implement something but am stuck on an error in XCode 4.5.2.  The following code is a simplified version that still replicates the error.  It occurs on the line where the method `Api::Enable` is defined and has something to do with the fact that there are no parameters when `Api::Enable` calls `this->T::Enable`

```
enum Enum
{
    FOO,
    BAR,
    BAZ,
};

template <typename T>
class Api
{
public:
    template <Enum E, bool On> void Enable() {static_cast<T *>(this)->Enable<E, On>();}
};

class ApiImpl : public Api<ApiImpl>
{
public:
    template <Enum E, bool On> void Enable() {}
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ApiImpl clsApi;
    clsApi.Enable<FOO, true>();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the error in Xcode: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUHtt.png.  I get the same error whether I use "Apple LLVM compiler 4.1" or "LLVM GCC 4.2".  MSVC Express 2010 compiles without error.

Note that adding a function parameter causes the error to disappear.  The following compiles fine:

```
enum Enum
{
    FOO,
    BAR,
    BAZ,
};

template <typename T>
class Api
{
public:
    template <Enum E , bool On> void Enable(unsigned int X) {static_cast<T *>(this)->Enable<E, On>(X);}
};

class ApiImpl : public Api<ApiImpl>
{
public:
    template <Enum E, bool On> void Enable(unsigned int) {}
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ApiImpl clsApi;
    clsApi.Enable<FOO, true>(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `template` keyword to resolve dependent template names:

```
template <Enum E, bool On> void Enable() {
    static_cast<T*>(this)->template Enable<E, On>();
}
```

C++11, `[temp.names]/4`:

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after . or -> in a postfix-expression or after a
>   nested-name-specifier in a qualified-id, and the object expression of the postfix-expression is type-dependent
>   or the nested-name-specifier in the qualified-id refers to a dependent type, but the name is not a member of
>   the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword template.
>   Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.

If `Enable()` is for example `template <typename T> void Enable(){}`, then clang shows an error: `error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'Enable' as a dependent template name`.

I don't know why it produces that irrelevant message in your case (when template arguments are not types). I think this can be posted as bug report. (I tested on clang 3.6 - the same).

Also, gcc 4.8 and 4.9 don't produce any errors on this code which I beleive is also incorrect.